# Django rest framework: override create() in ModelSerializer passing an extra parameter

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, overriding

I am looking for a way to properly ovverride the default `.create()` method of a `ModelSerializer` serializer in Django Rest Framework for dealing with an extra parameter.

In my original Django model I have just overridden the default`.save()` method for managing an `extra` param. Now `.save()` can be called also in this way: `.save(extra = 'foo')`.

I have to create a `ModelSerializer` mapping on that original Django model:

```
from OriginalModels.models import OriginalModel
from rest_framework import serializers

class OriginalModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    # model fields
    class Meta:
        model = OriginalModel
```

But in this way I can't pass the `extra` param to the model `.save()` method.

How can I properly override the `.create()` method of my `OriginalModelSerializer` class to take (eventually) this `extra` param into account?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Hmm.  this might not be the perfect answer given I don't know how you want to pass this "extra" in (ie. is it an extra field in a form normally, etc)

What you'd probably want to do is just represent foo as a field on the serializer.  Then it will be present in `validated_data` in `create`, then you can make `create` do something like the following

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    obj = OriginalModel.objects.create(**validated_data)
    obj.save(foo=validated_data['foo'])
    return obj
```

You'd probably want to look at the default implementation of create for some of the other things it does though (like remove many-to-many relationships, etc.).

Comment: The problem is that "extra" param is not a field of my `OrginalModel`. As far as I know, there is not a way to add a field to a `ModelSerializer` if it does not map to any regular field of  `OrginalModel`

Comment: You need to pop the `foo` field from `validated_data` before passing it to the model constructor, then this answer should work.

Comment: Be sure to include all other code defined in ModelSerializer' 'create' method: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/3.9.0/rest_framework/serializers.py#L905 otherwise with the above code you lose some predefined functionality.

Answer (score 15):

You can now do this in the view set (threw in user as a bonus ;) ):

```
class OriginalModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows OriginalModel classes to be viewed or edited.
    """
    serializer_class = OriginalModelSerializer
    queryset =  OriginalModel.objects.all()
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        user = None
        if self.request and hasattr(self.request, "user"):
            user = self.request.user
        serializer.save(user=user, foo='foo')
```

That way the Serializer can stay generic, i.e.:

```
class OriginalModelSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = OriginalModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: When would you put this logic inside view, serializer, model manager or even signal?

Comment: When you need separation of the functions.  I use the view, as it allows multiple views to use the same serializer.  I am a bit more strict around models, as logic that lands in models should be applicable system wide -- REST is a specific use case.  Signals are really for decoupling -- which is probably too much for this application, also signals complicate support, and I have enough to do without adding to support burden.  But, there is more than one way to do it.