# Saving a Serializer in Django

Tags: python, django, orm, model

When I'm trying to save a model object (its name here is 'RSS) in the view's post() it doesn't get saved, how can I save the model instance 'rss' from the view's post()?

In the Serializers class:

```
class RSSSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = RSS
        fields = ('feed_url', 'website_url', 'description', 'title')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        rss = RSS(**validated_data)
        rss.created_at =  datetime.now()
        rss.last_scan_time = '2001-01-01 00:00:00'
        rss.id = None
        return rss
```

In the View class:

```
class RSSList(APIView):
        def post(self, request):
                serializer = RSSSerializer(data=request.data)
                if serializer.is_valid():
                        print("saving rss post")
                        serializer.save()
                        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
                return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current `create` method instantiates a new `RSS` object but doesn't save it. Try this:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    rss = RSS.objects.create(**validated_data)
    rss.created_at = datetime.now()
    ...
    return rss.save()
```

More info: [Django rest framework: override create() in ModelSerializer passing an extra parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30650008/django-rest-framework-override-create-in-modelserializer-passing-an-extra-par)

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances

> If your object instances correspond to Django models you'll also want to ensure that these methods save the object to the database.