# How to pass arguments to model save method in django through serializer create method

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am saving a model like this

```
   if serializer.is_valid():
       message = serializer.save(version_info='55')
```

and I am passing a parameter called version_info and inside my serializer
I have the following code

```
class MessageSerializer(serilizer.Serializer):
    def create(self, validated_data, **kwargs):
        message = Message.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return message
```

**version_info** parameter is inside validated_data dictionary
but I want to pass this version_info to save method of my **Message** model which I have customize it to do some extra work while a message being saved
but it gives this error:
TypeError: Message() got an unexpected keyword argument 'version_info'
how can I pass the version_info parameter to save method of my model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Using the `context`

You can add it to the context when you construct the serializer, so:

```
serializer = MessageSerializer(data=data, context={'version_info': 55})
if serializer.is_valid():
    message = serializer.save()
```

and in the serializer you can access the context with:

```
class MessageSerializer(serilizer.Serializer):
    
    def create(self, validated_data, **kwargs):
        version_info = self.context['version_info']
        # do something …
        message = Message.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return message
```

## Popping the element from the `validated_data`

Another option where you still call `.save(version_info=55)` is popping the data from the validated data with:

```
class MessageSerializer(serilizer.Serializer):
    
    def create(self, validated_data, **kwargs):
        version_info = validated_data.pop('version_info', None)
        # do something …
        message = Message.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return message
```

this will return `None` for the `version_info` if you did not call it with `.save(version_info=55)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but how can i pass the version_info variable to save method of my Message model?

Comment: @YOUNGHUNTER: you create the model with `message = Message(**validated_data)` and then `message.save(version_info=version_info)`

Comment: I have no problem with passing data into seializer. I want to add a parameters into validated_data as const like: name = "James".

Comment: maybe like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/30652737/3319132